# Python parameters in recursive function

Tags: python

I am trying to solve an algorithm problem in leetCode(https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/).
I made the recursiveList function to solve this by recursion and put a variable newHead as a parameter.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    
    def recursiveList(self, head, newHead):
        if head.next == None:
            return ListNode(head.val)
        
        newHead.next = self.recursiveList(head.next, newHead)
        newHead = newHead.next
        return ListNode(head.val) 
    
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        if head == None:
            return None
        
        newHead = ListNode()
        resultHead = ListNode(0, newHead)
        
        newHead.next = self.recursiveList(head, newHead)
        
        return resultHead.next
```

result

```
Your input
[1,2,3,4,5]
Output
[0,1]
Expected
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

I found when recursiveList function returns ListNode value newHead resets. In other words `newHead = newHead.next` is not working when recursiveList returns value.
**below why `ListNode{val: 5, next: None}` turns to `ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 5, next: None}}` after return?**

Sorry for my bad English. Just in case I cant reply comments, thank you in advance!!!

```
Node = self.recursiveList(head.next, newHead)
print("newHead first : %s" % newHead)
newHead.next = Node
newHead = newHead.next
print("newHead second : %s" % newHead)
print("return!")
return ListNode(head.val)
```

result

```
newHead first : ListNode{val: 0, next: None}
newHead second : ListNode{val: 5, next: None}
return!
newHead first : ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 5, next: None}}
newHead second : ListNode{val: 4, next: None}
return!
newHead first : ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}
newHead second : ListNode{val: 3, next: None}
return!
newHead first : ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}
newHead second : ListNode{val: 2, next: None}
return!
```

Comment: "below why ListNode{val: 5, next: None} turns to ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 5, next: None}} after return?" Well, the `ListNode{val: 5, next: None}` is the result when you print `newHead`, but you don't return `newHead` but instead `ListNode(head.val)`. So why should they be the same?

Comment: Well i think python functions work by call by reference when i put class object as function parameter. Am i wrong? Actually i never returned ```newHead```, but ```newHead``` has changed. why does that happen?

Comment: Please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html